# Efficient way to check that dataframe's has a complete grid of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check whether all data within a dataframe from the top left hand corner of the dataframe to the bottom most right element is complete (the data should be filled in as a rectangle). If is has blank columns or rows after the main body of data this is fine (and it will have this).

Example of good and bad dataframes are below:

```
bad_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,""],["","","",""],[1,"",1,""],["","","",""]])
good_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,""],[1,1,1,""],[1,1,1,""],[1,1,1,""],["","","",""]])
```

The way I have done it is as follows

```
def not_rectangle_data(DataFrame):
    """
    This function will check if the data given to it is a "rectangle"
    """

    #removes all rows and columns that contain only blanks
    reduced_dataframe = DataFrame[DataFrame != ""].dropna(how="all",axis = 1).dropna(how="all",axis = 0)

    #removes all rows and columns that contain any blanks
    super_reduced_dataframe = reduced_dataframe.dropna(how="any",axis = 1).dropna(how="any",axis = 0)

    #Check that dataframe is not empty and that no column or no rows are half empty
    if not reduced_dataframe.empty and \
            super_reduced_dataframe.equals(reduced_dataframe):        

        #Check that columns in remain data are still present
        if ((max(reduced_dataframe.index) + 1) == reduced_dataframe.shape[0]) and \
            ((max(reduced_dataframe.columns) + 1) == reduced_dataframe.shape[1]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

However I feel like there should be a more concise way of doing this.

Many Thanks

Comment: always a int 1 when no blank data?

Comment: maybe you can convert it into an numpy array with `dataframe.values` then there are numpy functions to extract the upper and lower trinagle `np.triu( dataframe.values)` and then you can check that for `np.isna()` or other tests.

Comment: `bad_dataframe` also contains a rectangle with shape (1,3). Can you please describe your constraints more precisely?

Comment: @Frenchy no it can have anything. Ints or strings or floats.

Comment: @Chris bad_dataframe has data missing within it's "rectangle". So it's not "complete" inside the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def check_rectangle(df):
    non_zeros = np.nonzero(df.values)
    arr = np.zeros(np.max(non_zeros, 1)+1)
    np.add.at(arr, non_zeros, 1)
    return np.alltrue(arr)

check_rectangle(good_dataframe)
# True
check_rectangle(bad_dataframe)
# False
```

- `np.nonzero` grabs all indices that are not zero (`''` is considered zero here).
- `np.zeros(np.max(non_zeros, 1)+1)` creates smallest rectangle that fits the `non_zeros`.
- `np.add.at` added `1` to all non-zero places.
- Finally, `np.alltrue` returns `True` if the rectangle is filled, else `False`.

Comment: How very elegant. It works significantly faster than mine and is shorter. This is exactly what I wanted.